# Make element stick to the right on Mobile screens

Tags: mobile, responsive-design, csc

First time run across this issue.

I have an element that is positioned to the right of the screen, like that

```
.element {
  position:absolute;
  right:0
}
```

Everything works as expected on desktop, but starting to fail apart on small screen devices.
.element is no longer stuck to the right and appears rather on the left part. I suppose this is something to do with small screen devices ability to zoom in and out, but why this element not following the rule here.

PS. Tried with float:right, same effect.

Comment: have you given its parent position:relative; ?

Answer (score 0):

Please add more details of code, I am confident that the problem is not arising because of this part of the code, but rather because your media queries are not working correct or the positioning is being overridden elsewhere in subsequent CSS. If possible, create a jsfiddle with further glimpses of your actual work.